# O que é um Pentester?

Tags: terminologia, hacking

Navegando pela internet, vi alguns hackers falando que trabalham ou trabalharam como Pentesters e eu gostaria de entender mais sobre essa profissão. Há alguma diferença entre Pentester, Hacker e Programador / Engenheiro de Software ?

Comment: De forma resumida, são aqueles que procuram brechas e falhas de segurança, e "hacker" que é um termo usado de forma informal e as vezes errada, poderia ser um exemplo disto, no caso uma pessoa com capacidade/conhecimento de invasão pode usar seus conhecimentos para melhorar a segurança de softwares e redes, basicamente isto seria o tal PenTester, o "hacker" do "bem" (mais ou menos). Mas claro, tem ferramentas, conhecimento, experiencia, setores, softwares e nada é muito especifico, tanto que não adianta ter conhecimento em X ambiente esperando conseguir buscar brechas no ambiente Y ou Z.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento existe diferença entre um "Hacker do bem" e um Pentester.

Comment: @CypherPotato existe é uma maneira muito errada de usar o termo hacker, como eu disse no começo, mas se eu pegar pra malhar o povo (não aqui das postagens, mas de um todo, principalmente os "millennials" e cia) ai vai começar uma discussão que não cabe aqui. Tem muita gente que que por smoking (Black-tie) em um pato e acha que algo mudou. É capaz de um usuário leigo deixar a senha dele gravada no "lembrar", outra pessoa consegue copiar ai já chamam de "hacker";

Comment: @CypherPotato você criou a tag [tag:hacking], pretende contextualizar com um Wiki?

Comment: Vou começar com um fragmento, @GuilhermeNascimento .

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento hackers já não são do bem ? Por que ficar falando o tempo todo "do bem" se quem faz o mal são os crackers ?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Ambos são diferentes um do outro.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 a gravidade é do bem ou é do mal? Se você ficar parado ela vai te machucar? Se você pular de uma montanha ela vai te machucar? Talvez não seja a melhor "metáfora". Mas vou deixar a conversa de lado porque em questão de *"termos de mercado"* eu não sou a melhor pessoa para falar.... ps: só pra constar, "hacker" e "bem" estão entre aspas, logo não disse exatamente "hacker" muito menos exatamente "bem"

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 essa discussão foi citada no chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53373807#53373807

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existe diferença entre as quatro profissões sim, e respondendo sua pergunta,

## Pentester

Também é conhecido como *Testador de Penetração*, *Avaliador de Invasão*. Como seu nome já diz, um Pentester é responsável por mapear todas as possíveis vulnerabilidades quando o assunto é invasão. Invasão seria qualquer acesso indesejado, seja feita por um hacker ou até por um *cliente*. O Pentester deve analisar todas as possíveis formas de introdução mal-intencionada num sistema e mapear estas vulnerabilidades para que possam ser corrigidas.

Um teste de invasão avalia se um sistema está apto à receber ataques ou cyber-ataques. Diferente do Hacker, o Pentester é focado apenas em invasão de sistemas. Não está limitado à um tipo de sistema ou plataforma, como autenticação e banco de dados, mas sim qualquer outro acesso mal-intencionado.

## Hacker ético

Os Hackers são responsáveis por uma ampla região de negação de sistema. Também é um Pentester, mas envolve outras responsabilidades: um hacker ético (contratado) mapeia todas as possíveis vulnerabilidades de um sistema para que não possam ser invadidas por outros hackers.

Técnicas de invasão é um assunto que está dentro de Hackers. Mas *"hackear"* não é apenas isso.

Um hacker não-ético faz sua invasão por vontade própria, se aproveita do sistema e ganha acesso ao mesmo. Um hacker ético faz a invasão, mas não se aproveita. Muitas vezes é contratado diretamente para testar o sistema. Outros fazem por boas intenções. Os autores de CVEs são considerados Hackers Éticos.

## Engenheiro de Software

Nem sempre é um programador. Neste assunto, ele é responsável por demandar as avaliações feitas pelos Pentesters/Hackers. Ele é o responsável pela aplicação da correção da vulnerabilidade, e então passada para o programador/desenvolvedor implementar explicitamente tal correção.

Os engenheiros de softwares também são os responsáveis pela construção estruturada do software que será então invadido.

## Programador

Não vou definir o que é um programador, mas neste assunto, ele é o responsável por implementar as demandas vindas do Engenheiro de Software. É o desenvolvedor de softwares que irá implementar tais correções.

---

Na prática, existem pessoas que são estes quatro em um só. Existem equipes mais dividas onde separam cada função. Normalmente sistemas grandes tem estes quatro responsáveis, mas não posso garantir isso.

Comment: Aproveitando que estamos falando deste assunto, você poderia me dizer se é ilegal ou não invadir um sistema sem autorização para descobrir uma falha e reportar ao dono sobre o problema ?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 é e não é. Muitas vezes os hackers que descobrem as vulnerabilidades tentam primeiro vendê-las de forma anônima, e se a empresa recusa, eles podem vender para outras empresas interessadas ou outros hackers. Tudo funciona de forma anônima, alguns ganharam sua vida com isso. Algumas empresas publicam suas vulnerabilidades já corrigidas como CVEs.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 ilegal onde? Depende. No Brasil, se vc burlou qq mecanismo e obteve alguma informação com isso, é ilegal sim: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lei_Carolina_Dieckmann - PS: eu entendo que essa pergunta fora de escopo, por se tratar de uma questão de mercado e não de programação (tão relevante quanto perguntar se é melhor comprar uma cadeira Aeron, uma New Ergon ou uma genérica de 300 reais - importantissima diferença para o programador, mas tambem fora de escopo) mas como meu voto é vinculante como moderador, prefiro que a comunidade decida os primeiros votos.